# Kafka connector Elasticsearch topics.regex

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

The version I used is confluent kafka 5.1.14

I was trying to run the Kafka connector Elasticsearch to send data from Kafka to Elasticsearch
I've test this configuration on standalone mode and everything works fine.
here is the standalone config for elasticsearch sink

```
name=elasticsearch-sink-standalone
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics.regex=^[a-zA-Z0-9]((?!-raw$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_])+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
connection.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
type.name=_doc
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

But when I use same setting to create the sink on distributed mode, it would have error.
This is the post body of the request while creating the sink

```
{
 "name" : "connector-test",
 "config" : {
  "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max" : "1",
  "topics.regex" : "^[a-zA-Z0-9]((?!-raw$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_])+[a-zA-Z0-9]$", 
  "connection.url" : "http://elasitcsearch:9200",
  "type.name" : "_doc",
  "key.ignore" : "true",
  "schema.ignore" : "true"
 }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
[2020-08-04 18:18:35,911] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=connector-test-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:492)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:344)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"status-task-connector-test-0"; line: 1, column: 8]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"status-task-connector-test-0"; line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3532)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2627)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4043)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2572)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:342)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:492)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-08-04 18:18:35,912] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=connector-test-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

I can use the distributed mode with other regex so I suppose the error is caused by regex.
But what confused me is that the standalone mode can work with this regex.

Both of standalone mode and distributed mode are run with (I'm not sure if this information helps)

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Please tell me if I need to provide more information
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem here is the regex. The stacktrace clearly shows that a message is trying to be serialized after being polled from the source system (which in this case is Kafka since the connector is a sink) and a something-2-json error is happening. You need to understand which format those records are that are causing the transformation error.

The regex is used to know which topics the connector should read the records from, and this seems to be working as expected.